# Laravel scheduled tasks created by users

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, schedule, cron-task, crontrigger

I have a very big database that consisted of original posts.

I send these posts to my users. So here is where I lost.
I want my users to create scheduled tasks by selecting time intervals like "every 15 mins, every 30 mins." via the form.

The system will send x amount of posts to the users according to the periods their choose.

I have 4-5K users. So it'll be around 4-5k scheduled tasks.
How may i do that? I'll be more than glad if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... well you could have 1 task that can do the query and gather up what needs to go out, then it could fire of some jobs to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the scheduled commands for the times that users want to select and put the commands in the scheduler and execute the commands are the same times

ex:

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command(CommandEveryMinute::class)->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command(CommandEveryTwoMinutes::class)->everyTwoMinutes();
}
```